# Cancel events in bulk in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

How can I cancel a lot of events, at the same time, from Google Calendar?

I'm trying to remove all the events that were from the last year in my calendar.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gcaltoolkit.com/

Looks promising although I have never used it myself

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can use http://elementi.ws/gcalendarcleaner